# Does volatile in java allow for instances to be deleted?

Tags: java, android, database, android-room, volatile

I am watching a video tutorial on Room db. In the video, the instructor says:

"Volatile just means that the instance will be able to get rid of itself or remove itself if need be."

However, based on my understanding, volatile means that the variable will be stored in the main memory rather than taken from the cache.

This post confirmed that as well: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html

How does volatile allow for an instance to remove itself?

Thanks!

Comment: The instructor's comment makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Agreed, haha @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPU caches are always coherent; it is the source of truth; so memory could be completely out of sync.. indefinitely.. perfectly fine. A write of a volatile variable doesn't trigger the whole cache to be flushed to main memory; that would be extremely inefficient. Even a single cache line isn't force to flush to main memory.

What typically is meant (on X86) with 'flushing' to main memory is that when a volatile store is done, the CPU waits for the stores in the store buffer to be committed to the cache before allowing any loads to execute. This prevents the reordering of an older store with a newer load to a different address.

The "remove itself" stuff makes no sense at all.

This article is incorrect.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html

This is not how it works. Caches are synchronized using a cache coherence protocol like MESI. So a write to a cacheline on one CPU will always lead to the copies of the cacheline in the other CPU to be invalidated.

Warning: when dealing with the JMM it is best to keep it fully abstract and not reason about implementation concerns like cache invalidation etc. It is fun.. but you can shoot yourself very easily in the foot.

Comment: Thank you for your response. "What typically is meant (on X86) with 'flushing' to main memory is that when a volatile store is done, the CPU waits for the stores in the store buffer to be committed to the cache before allowing any loads to execute.". Does it commit to the main memory after committing to the cache? Thanks.

Comment: Also, "This is not how it works. Caches are synchronized using a cache coherence protocol like MESI. So a write to a cacheline on one CPU will always lead to the copies of the cacheline in the other CPU to be invalidated." What exactly do you mean by this? I'm quite new to this area, so would appreciate if you could maybe rephrase it simpler. Thank you. Appreciate it.

Comment: It doesn't commit to main memory; it commits to the cache. The cache is the source of truth. Perhaps a write to the cache is visible to main memory.... at some point in the future. Or perhaps never. Memory is just overflow for the cache.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But then what's the difference from declaring something as volatile, rather than not? Doesn't everything automatically commit to the cache? I thought volatile committed to the main memory based on the articles on the Internet. Thank you.

Comment: The cache provides cache coherence. On a basic level it means that if CPU1 does a store, and CPU2 does a load and sees that store and then CPU3 does a load, CPU3 should not see a previous value.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So without volatile there wouldn't be cache coherence?

Comment: Caches are always coherent. No matter if something is volatile or not. This goes for X86 and ARM and any modern CPU I know of.

Comment: Without volatile 2 things can fail. Either the compiler can reorder loads/stores; so if the compiler messes up your code, then it doesn't matter how strong the memory model of the CPU is. Also the CPU can reorder loads and stores. On the X86 only an older store can be reordered with a newer load to a different address. So a volatile write needs to prevent that situation:

https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/on-the-fence-with-dependencies/

Comment: On the ARM it requires some more effort because it has a weak memory model and therefor there is a split between regular loads (LDR) and stores (STR) that don't provide ordering and there are synchronizing loads and stores. A synchronizing store is STLR that provides release semantics. And there are 2 synchronizing loads: LDAR and LDAPR. The LDAR can't be reordered with an earlier STLR to a different address; while an LDAPR can. But both provide acquire semantics. So in this case the compiler needs to make sure that emits the appropriate synchronizing load/store instructions.

Comment: So on the X86 there is almost no difference between plain loads and stores and volatiles loads and stores (apart from dealing with the store load reordering). And the caches are completely unaware if their cachelines contain any fields that are volatile or not.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed explanation. Appreciate it.